# How to put parentheses and brackets to the intervals

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]I want the intervals to be of the form [161,168) and [182,189], instead of as they appear in the attached image, that is to say, that the intervals have parentheses and brackets.
[image]

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra) 

LI <- sample(155:165, 1) 
a <-sample(5:10, 1) 
lim <-seq ( from =LI ,by=a , length =5)
limites <- function (m ){
v <-NULL
for (i in 1: m){
v <-c(v , paste ( lim [i] ," -" , lim [i +1]) )
}
v
}
intervalos <- limites (4)
frecuencias <- sample (10:30 ,4)
tabla <-data.frame (intervalos , frecuencias)
colnames ( tabla ) <-c("Intervalos" ,"Frecuencias ")
marcasdeclase <- function (v){
vect <-NULL
n <- length (v) -1
for (k in 1: n) vect <-c( vect , mean (c(v[ k],v[k +1]) ) )
vect
}



<<echo=FALSE, results=hide, fig=TRUE,width=7.5,height=4>>=

tabla <-data.frame (intervalos , frecuencias )
colnames (tabla) <-c("Intervalos" ,"Frecuencias ")

grid.table(tabla, rows = NULL)

@
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are building those values as strings in the `limites` function. Change that function to include the appropriate parentheses/brackets.

```
limites <- function (m ){
  v <-NULL
  for (i in 1: m){
    v <-c(v , paste ("[", lim [i] ," -" , lim [i +1], ifelse(i==m,"]",")")))
  }
  v
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is perfect, although there is a little space between the number and the parenthesis or bracket. Attached image, above.

Comment: Well, `paste()` adds space between terms by default. Use `paste0()` instead if you don’t want that.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much, although it is not allowed to say it. Above is the image with the result.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need a `for` loop, we can work on `lim` as a vector.
2. You control the formatting directly with your `paste`, I suggest `sprintf` as an alternative.

```r
lim <- c(158L, 166L, 174L, 182L, 190L)
sprintf("[%d-%d%s",
        lim[-length(lim)], lim[-1],
        c(rep(")", length(lim) - 2), "]"))
# [1] "[158-166)" "[166-174)" "[174-182)" "[182-190]"
```

Steps:

- `"[%d-%d%s"` is placing two integers (`%d`) and a string (`%s`) amid the static chars `[` and `-`; you can see more about the `%`-codes at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html
- the first digit for each output string needs to be all except the last of `lim`, ergo `lim[-length(lim)]` which returns `c(158L, 166L, 174L, 182L)`;
- similarly, the second digit for each output string should be all except the first, so `lim[-1]` returns `c(166L, 174L, 182L, 190L)`
- we want to end each string with `)` for all except the last number, so we repeat `")"` for `length(lim)-2` times, and then a single `"]"`.

Side note: I suggest your `limites` function should not reach out of its scope to find `lim`, perhaps pass it as the argument.

```r
limites <- function(x, n = length(x) - 1) {
  n <- min(n, length(x) - 1)
  sprintf("[%d-%d%s", x[1:n], x[-1][1:n], c(rep(")", n-1), "]"))
}
limites(lim)
# [1] "[158-166)" "[166-174)" "[174-182)" "[182-190]"
limites(lim, 4)
# [1] "[158-166)" "[166-174)" "[174-182)" "[182-190]"
limites(lim, 3)
# [1] "[158-166)" "[166-174)" "[174-182]"
```

(Feel free to add spaces around the `%d` as desired, as long as the `%` and `d`/`s`/... have no space between them.)